# Change the position of string within a larger string in R

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I have a character column, that looks like this:

```
names <- c("Isle North East", "London Northwestern", "Bedfordshire North East", "Southwark and Bermondsey North East",
           "Middlesbrough South and Cleveland East")
```

And I am trying to do is to move the expression `"North East"` to before whatever word appears before it. So if the string is XXXX XXXX North East I want it to be "XXXX North East XXXX" for example. Maybe it is easier if I show the solution I am looking for:

```
ideal.names <- c("North East Isle", "London Northwestern", "North East Bedfordshire", "Southward and North East Bermondsey",
             "Middlesbrough South and Cleveland East")
```

I've trying different things like:

```
c(sub('^(.*) North East', 'North East \\1', names))
```

But this returns the following:

```
[1] "North East Isle"                        "London Northwestern"                   
[3] "North East Bedfordshire"                "North East Southwark and Bermondsey"   
[5] "Middlesbrough South and Cleveland East"
```

So the issue is that this moves the string `North East` to the beginning of the string and not to before the word that precedes it. So I get `North East Southwark and Bermondsey` instead of `Southward and North East Bermondsey`, which is what I wanted.
Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
gsub('(\\S+) (North East)', '\\2 \\1', names)
## => [1] "North East Isle"                        "London Northwestern"                    "North East Bedfordshire"                "Southwark and North East Bermondsey"   
##    [5] "Middlesbrough South and Cleveland East"
```

*Details*

- `(\S+)` - Group 1 (`\1`): one or more non-whitespace
- - a space
- `(North East)` - Group 2 (`\2`): `North East` string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w8CKp4/1).

Comment: Or, `gsub("(\\w+)(\\W+)(North East)", "\\3\\2\\1", names)` (or `gsub("(*UCP)(\\w+)(\\W+)(North East)", "\\3\\2\\1", names, perl=TRUE)` to support Unicode), if you need to handle any spaces and punctuation between the words. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w8CKp4/2).